# How to draw histogram chart for time series in SAS using proc gchart

Tags: graph, sas, gchart

I need to draw a histogram to make comparison between two series. I have the following code, but the proc gchart is not working.

```
data test;
input date $ irate  ppi   savings   income  cpi;
datalines;
JUN1990 8.43    114.3   2.412   83.83   129.9
JUL1990 8.76    114.5   2.473   68.147  130.4
AUG1990 8.94    116.5   4.594   84.205  131.6
SEP1990 8.85    118.4   3.893   84.016  132.7
OCT1990 8.67    120.8   3.816   52.269  133.5
NOV1990 8.51    120.1   5.35    97.008  133.8
DEC1990 8.13    118.7   4.253   81.292  133.8
JAN1991 7.98    119     3.872   57.779  134.6
FEB1991 7.92    117.2   4.249   62.566  134.8
MAR1991 8.09    116.2   6.117   77.929  135
APR1991 8.31    116     3.69    92.044  135.2
MAY1991 8.22    116.5   3.798   59.509  135.6
JUN1991 8.02    116.3   1.812   59.549  136
JUL1991 7.68    116     2.951   49.197  136.2
;
run;

proc reg data=test;
model irate = ppi  savings  income  cpi /p;
output out=b p=py;
run;
quit;

axis1 minor=none major=(h=1) label=none 
order=(0 to 120000 by 10000) ; 
axis2 major=(height=1) value=none 
label=none offset=(5, 5)pct ; 
axis3 label=none nobrackets ; 
axis4 minor=none major=(h=1) label=none 
order=(0 to 120000 by 60000) ; 
axis5 minor=none major=(h=1) label=none 
order=(0 to 120000 by 20000) ; 
axis6 minor=none major=(h=1) label=none 
order=(0 to 119000 by 17000) ; 
pattern1 c=ligr ; 
pattern2 c=gray ; 

proc gchart data=test ; 
 title 'Too Many' ; 
 vbar group /

 sumvar=value2 group=date 
 noframe nolegend 
 subgroup=group 
 raxis=axis1 maxis=axis2 gaxis=axis3 
 width=12 space=0 gspace=4 
 coutline=same ; 
 format date monname3. value2 comma10.0; 
 run ; 
 title 'Odd Tick Mark Intervals' ; 
 vbar group / 
 sumvar=value2 group=date 
 subgroup=group 
 noframe nolegend 
 raxis=axis6 maxis=axis2 gaxis=axis3 
 width=12 space=0 gspace=4 
 coutline=same ; 
 format date monname3. value2 comma10.0; 
 run ; 
 quit ; 

I want to make the final graph like this:
```

[image]

Can someone help me to change the proc gchart code or you can use your own method to do this?

Comment: What version of SAS?

Comment: 9.4, but I want the solution can meet 9.3. Thanks!

Comment: Where does value2 come from? Your code doesn't seem to match your data, and what do you expect from the proc reg?

Comment: This seems a bit too much code to be asking for, but perhaps someone else is willing to answer it. You can try here for a link that produces a similar chart. You may need to summarize your data first. The code and sample data is available. http://robslink.com/SAS/democd7/col1.htm

Comment: In proc reg, I only need three variables: irate and py and date. You can ignore the proc chart, and use what you familiar with, either in 9.3 or 9.4.

Comment: I really want you to give me a hand. I saw the link but it seems too different because the type of that chart is not time series, it is by group. So please give me the solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, this falls more into consulting than general help for me now. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else mentioned - your test data does not contain the variables GROUP and VALUE2 that you are trying to call in your PROC GCHART.  I think to match your example, you will need to separate the date into month and year in order to chart year in side-by side bars.  Below is some GCHART code that creates a histogram similar to your example.  You will need to change the response variable to what you are trying to chart.

Hope this helps.

```
*** CREATE MONTH AND YEAR AS SEPARATE VARIABLES ***;
data test_fix;
    set test;

    *** FIRST CONVERT DATE FROM CHARACTER STRING TO NUMERIC SAS DATE VARIABLE ***;
    date_sas=input(date, ANYDTDTE.); 

    *** USE SAS DATE VARIABLE TO GET MONTH AND YEAR AS NUMERIC VARIABLES ***;
    month=month(date_sas);
    year=year(date_sas);
run;

proc print data=test_fix;
    format date_sas mmddyy10.;
run;

axis1 label=('MONTH') offset=(5,5); 
axis2 label=none value=none;     
axis3 label=(a=90 'PPI') ;

pattern1 v=solid color=greyc0;  *** LIGHT GREY ***;
pattern2 v=solid color=grey40;  *** DARY GREY ***;

proc gchart data=test_fix;
    vbar year / 
        type=sum sumvar=ppi 
        group=month subgroup=year
        discrete
        space=0
        gaxis=axis1 /* GROUP AXIS (X-AXIS) - MONTH */
        maxis=axis2 /* MID POINT AXIS (X-AXIS) - YEAR */
        raxis=axis3 /* RESPONSE AXIS (Y-AXIS) - PPI */
;
run;
quit;
```